# Symbolically multiply infinite sums in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm writing software which uses SymPy to symbolically write code, and I've encountered multiplied sums that I need to simplify. The algorithm I'm using calls for the use of the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) to convert two sums multiplied by each other into a double sum. Below is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
from sympy import Sum, Function, Symbol, oo

# Define variables
n = Symbol('n')
x = Symbol('x')
t = Symbol('t')

# Define functions
theta = Function('theta')(t)
p = Function('p')(n,x)
q = Function('q')(n,x)

# Create Summations
pSum = Sum(p*theta**n, (n,0,oo))
qSum = Sum(q*theta**n, (n,0,oo))

# Multiply
out = pSum * qSum
print(out)
>>> Sum(p(n, x)*theta(t)**n, (n, 0, oo))*Sum(q(n, x)*theta(t)**n, (n, 0, oo))
```

I need to convert this to

```
print(out)
>>> Sum(Sum((p(i, x)*q(n-i, x))*theta**n, (i, 0, n)), (n, 0, oo))
```

My approach at this was importing `Sum` and defining a class that inherits from `Sum`.  I then define the `__mul__` operator to do what I want.  This works for simple cases, but in more complicated cases, it won't work. In this example, the first case works, but the next one won't multiply because the * isn't calling `__mul__` when already in SymPy.

```
import sympy
from sympy import expand, Function, Symbol, oo, diff, Sum, Derivative

class Sum2(Sum):

    # Overriding the __mul__ method.
    def __mul__(self, other):

        if isinstance(other, Sum2):
            i = Symbol('i')
            n = Symbol('n')
            return Sum2(Sum(self.args[0].subs(n, i)*other.args[0].subs(n, n-i), (i,0,n)), (n,0,oo))

        else:
            super().__mul__(other)

x = Symbol('x')
t = Symbol('t')
n = Symbol('n')

f = Function('f')(n, x)
a = Sum2(f*t**n, (n,0,oo))

# Works
print(a*a)

# Doesn't work.
c = (Derivative(a,x)*a).doit()
print(c)
print(c.doit())
print(expand(c))
```

I've tried a similar approach, inheriting from `Function` instead.  Same problem. Perhaps `__mul__` wasn't the right function to redefine? How can I allow infinite sums to be multiplied in this way?

Comment: I think you've got the right idea. `__mul__` will have to work harder to find the partner, however: it might be in the term of an Add or a factor of a Mul.